# Report only first event of of model for each item - Rails model/view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, view, model

I'm working on a problem when the a product has_many product_selections. I'm trying to report the history of the product - one aspect of which includes getting the first time each  product in my array was selected in order to determine how long said product has been in circulation.

In my product_selection model:

```
belongs_to :product
def time_since_first_use
  (Time.now - self[0].staged_at)
end 
# staged_at is a datetime attribute
```

The product model then picks this up:

```
def tag_time_since_first_use
  self.product_selections.time_since_first_use
end
```

And I try to render it in the view (general formatting is simplified):

```
<% @products.order(created_at: :desc).each do |product| %>
   <%= humanize_seconds(product.tag_time_since_first_use)%>
<%end%>
```

I had the [0] selection on the product model initially, and it rendered a repeated value for every item in the product list. How do I fix this?

Comment: ok, so you only need `staged_at` of the first product_selection for the calculation?

Comment: Exactly. Each `product_selection` is like an event in the history of the `product`, so I need to be able to grab the first `selection`'s `staged_at` attribute. I'm going to plug it into a calculation `Time.now - [product.first_time_staged_method]` to get the amount of time it's been in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Product
  def tag_time_since_first_use
    Time.now - product_selections.order(staged_at: :asc).first.staged_at
  end
end
```

If you're using the `tag_time_since_first_use` frequently, it will be better to save the value in a `staged_at` attribute on the product, when the first `product_selection` is created for the product to avoid querying each time.